# How can I find Z?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Question: Joint Density of (x,y) = $$f_{(x,y)}  = 
    \begin{cases}
            x+y, &         \text{if } 0<x<1, 0<y<1\\
            0, &            \text{elsewhere}.
    \end{cases}$$

Find the density of $Z=\text{XY}$

My answer:

Take double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{z}\int_{0}^{z/x} (x+y)  \,dy \,dx$$

However, this double integral diverges when taking the second integral:

$$\int_{0}^{z} z+\frac{z^2}{2x^2} \,dx$$

which obviously should not be the case.

So how to solve this question?

Comment: Should the upper limit of the inner integral be $\text{min}(z/x, 1)$?

Comment: First of all I would calculate the (marginal) pdf's.

Comment: Ok. I got $f_X = \frac{2x+1}{2}$ and $f_Y = \frac{2y+1}{2}$. So is Z just their product?

Comment: @CaporalFourrier I got the same pdfs. Then I used [this formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482248/probability-distribution-of-the-product-of-two-dependent-random-variables). Unfortunately the integral does not converge too [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=int_0%5E1+%28x%2B1%2F2%29*%28z%2Fx%2B1%2F2%29%2F%7Cx%7C+dx). My advice does not really help. Maybe better to follow the hint of user51547.

Answer (score 2):

First, find the distribution function of $Z$:
\begin{align*}F_Z(z)&=\text{P}[XY\leq z]\\
&=\text{P}[(X,Y)\in \{(x,y):x\leq z/y\}]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{z/y}f(x,y)dxdy.\end{align*}
Use Leibniz rule to get that the density function of $Z$ is:
\begin{align*}
f_Z(z)=F_Z'(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(z/y,y)dy.
\end{align*}
This is just an easy integral.

**Edit.** To solve the integral above we have to consider the system of inequalities
$$0<y<1,\ 0<\frac{z}{y}<1.$$
This is the region where $f(z/y,y)$ is not zero. Notice that for $z\notin \left]0,1\right[$ this has no solution, and therefore $f_Z(z)=0$ for all $z$ outside $\left]0,1\right[$.

On the other hand, for $0<z<1$ we have
$z<y<1$ and so
$$f_Z(z)=\int_z^1\left(\frac{z}{y}+y\right)dy.$$

Comment: Shouldn't the lower limits be zero for both and the upper limit for the outer one be z?

Comment: Could you solve it explicitly, please? I did essentially the same thing but the integral still diverges...

Comment: Notice that you only have the inequality $x\leq z/y$, so $x$ can be as small as you want. I'll solve now the integral explicitly.